# how to link a nickname with a keychain

Tags: swift, keychain

Before, I was storing sensitive data(email, nickame, and password) in a json file. Now I am storing the email and the password into keychains ( kSecAttrAccount is the email)
But I have no ideea how can I store the nickname in the keychain. Or where can I store the nickname so it gets linked with a specific keychain.

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


func save(account: String, password: String) {
    
    do {
        try KeychainManager.save(
            service: "loseamp",
            account: account,
            password: password.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data())
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func getPassword(account: String, password: String) {
    guard let data = KeychainManager.get(
        service: "loseamp",
        account: account
    ) else {
        print("Failed to read password")
        return
    }
    let password = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
    print("read password here: \(password)")
}



class KeychainManager {
    enum KeychainError: Error {
        case duplicateEntry
        case unknown(OSStatus)
    }
    static func save(service: String, account: String, password: Data) throws {
        // service, account, password, class, data
        let query: [String: AnyObject] = [
            kSecAttrService as String: service as AnyObject,
            kSecAttrAccount as String: account as AnyObject,
            kSecValueData as String: password as AnyObject,
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword
        ]
        let status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
        guard status != errSecDuplicateItem else {
            throw KeychainError.duplicateEntry
        }
        guard status == errSecSuccess else {
            throw KeychainError.unknown(status)
        }
    }
    static func get(service: String, account: String) -> Data? {
        // service, account, password, class, data
        let query: [String: AnyObject] = [
            kSecAttrService as String: service as AnyObject,
            kSecAttrAccount as String: account as AnyObject,
            kSecReturnData as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne
        ]
        var result: AnyObject?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &result)
        print("Read status: \(status)")
        return result as? Data
        
    }
    func update(service: String, account: String, password: Data) {
        let query = [
            kSecAttrService: service as AnyObject,
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrAccount: account as AnyObject,
        ] as CFDictionary
        
        let updatedData = [kSecValueData: password] as CFDictionary
        SecItemUpdate(query, updatedData)
    }
    func delete(service: String, account: String) {
        let query = [
            kSecAttrService: service as AnyObject,
            kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrAccount: account as AnyObject
        ] as CFDictionary
        SecItemDelete(query)
    }
    func isEmailDuplicate(service: String, account: String) -> Bool {
        let query: [String: AnyObject] = [
            kSecAttrService as String: service as AnyObject,
            kSecAttrAccount as String: account as AnyObject,
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword
        ]
        let status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
        return status == errSecDuplicateItem
    }
}
```

Comment: But the nickname isn't secret right, it's not sensitive information like a password? I would suggest you link the nickname (and possibly other attributes) to an email address outside of the keychain.

Comment: Yes, nickname isn't secret. I am creating a music player and I wanted to use the nickname just to display a message like: "Hello <username>" somewhere on the main view of the player. But the email is stored in the keychain(in this case, email is sensitive data). Do you suggest creating a dictionary, where I store the email and the nickname, and then encode it into a json? But again the email is secret so it would be counterintuitive to do this.

Comment: Are you sure the email is secret, isn't that the account name? Account names aren't secret usually and are displayed in clear text unlike passwords.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I thought everything that I store in a keychain is (secret) data. Before using keychain I was using a json for every attribute and some user recommended me to use keychain. This means I didn't understood it properly.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson do you have any idea where the keychains are stored? I can't find them in the 'keychain access' app.